# Arduino wiring bug

Tags: arduino

Seems that there is something wrong with my Arduino connection to run this simple code where I can control an LED using a button.  The problem is that the LED is always turned on. My code is correct but still something is wrong. I think it is something related to resistors.

Could someone help me?

Here are my connections:

[image]

Comment: What was the reason the devices are wire like that to begin with? There must be at least a million tutorials available how to wire them correctly. And we don't see your code either, so we can't know if it is correct or not, it might not work even if the board was wired properly. Post the code and explain how it expects to read the button to control the LED.

Comment: `My code is correct` ... how do you know this?

Answer (score 2):

Your switch is wired incorrectly and your LED should have a series current-limiting resistor.